# Sphere-Cylinder surface integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals, spheres

I'm stuck in this exercise:

A solid is given which is the union of the cylindrical segment $$x^2+y^2 \le1,0 \le z \le2$$ and the half of the sphere $$x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2\le1 , z\ge2$$
Calculate the flux $$\iint_SF\cdot dS$$ where $$F(x,y,z) =(1,-1,z) $$
Initially, I thought of using Cylindrical coordinates to calculate the integral for the Cylinder and then use Spherical Coordinates to do the same for the sphere, but that doesn't seem right. Then, I thought of using the equations given to find the intersection equation but, honestly, I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: Do you mean _union_ instead of _intersection_ and is the sphere supposed to be a unit lower (or the cylindrical segment a unit higher)...? Now you have a cylindrical segment followed by a "gap" followed by the upper half of a sphere.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for noticing xD.
The sphere's center is on (0,0,2) and it's defined for z>=2

Comment: But the cylindrical segment doesn't run up to 2, but just until 1... so there's still a gap? Is it supposed to be like this, two disjoint solids?

Comment: Eeh, I messed up. Yes, it does go until 2. I edited it.

Comment: I've go to go now so no time for a real answer, but do you know the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)?

Comment: Now define $S$, and we can start working.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you fixed the solid, I'm assuming that $S$ is its (closed) boundary; i.e. a cylindrical segment with half a sphere as a cap.

If you want to calculate the flux as a surface integral directly, you'll need to split it up in:

- the bottom of the cylindrical segment;
- the side of the cylindrical segment;
- the half sphere on top.

Because you're (probably) looking for the flux through a closed surface, I hope you know about the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) and if not, it's worth checking out. It states:
$$\iint_SF\cdot dS = \iiint_G \nabla \cdot F \, dV$$
where $G$ is the given solid with boundary $S$.

The triple integral is easier to compute (in cylindrical coordinates) and in your case not even necessary, as $\nabla F = 1$; so the integral simplifies to finding the volume:
$$\iint_SF\cdot dS = \iiint_G 1 \, dV = \mbox{Vol}\,(G)$$
And you can find that with basic formulas to avoid any integration at all.